# Java MouseClicked Not Working When Run With awt Canvas

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent

For a Java program, I need to detect the click of a mouse. I imported `import java.awt.event.*;`. And ran this:

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Click position (X, Y):  " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
    }
}
```

When this is run, I don't get any output when I click on the screen.

This is what the start of my class looks like:

```
class Drawing extends Canvas implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I am on mac and another post ([JAVA mouseClicked event doesnt get fired on the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261913/java-mouseclicked-event-doesnt-get-fired-on-the-mac)) suggests that there might be something wrong with using a mac.

Comment: The linked question suggests that there maybe a problem when running on vmware.  Are you running on vmware?  If not, did you try doing like the example provided in the answer?

Comment: I am not running on vmware, this is a native mac computer. @ScaryWombat

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

The listener needs to be added to a component e.g. a button, panel etc.

```
public class MouseEventDemo implements MouseListener {
    //where initialization occurs:
    //Register for mouse events on blankArea and the panel.
    blankArea.addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
...


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   System.out.println ("Mouse clicked (# of clicks: "
                + e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
}
```